# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' array

Tags: c#, json

```
public class Product
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int   [] categories { get; set; }
}

var parentstl = from parentstyle in DBB.vParentStyles
                select new
                {
                    parentstyle.name,
                    parentstyle.description,
                    parentstyle.price,
                    Categories = parentstyle.categories.ToArray(),
                };

foreach (var pstl in parentstl)
{
    request.AddBody(new Product
    {
        name = pstl.name,
        description = pstl.description,
        price = (Decimal)pstl.price,
        **categories = new int[]{pstl.categories}.ToArray()**
    });
}
```

I get this error: **Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.**

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: I'm surprised it gets even that far, given that you've got `Categories` in your anonymous type, but you're using `categories` in your later block. It would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program, properly formatted...

Comment: What is the type of your `parentstyle`?

Comment: Is the parentstyle.categories elements convertible to int?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq, change this:

```
**categories = new int[]{pstl.categories}.ToArray()**
```

to this:

```
categories = pstl.categories.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: `Select(int.Parse)` will work just fine, no need for an extra lambda

Comment: yep it definitely would.  I was hoping writing it out would give a clear explanation

Comment: It gives me this error:Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I need output like this. But I get an error

'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnum‌​erable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Preferred Output:Value = "**{\"name\":\"000TEST\",\"description\":\"This is Test Item\",\"price\":\"19.99\",\"categories\":[141,163],\"type\":\"physical}”**